# Linq-to-Entities Aggregate a column that is calculated in an external function

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I want to Sum of the calculated column Red which is calculated in the Function IsRed() that return an integer.

When I run the query I get the following error: Method 'Int32 IsRed(Int32)' has no supported translation to SQL.

How should I rewrite this to get it to work.Thanks.

```
From xx In 
    (From l In L3s
    Join a In BLs On l.L3ID Equals a.L3ID
    Order By l.ID
    Select PID = l.ID,
    Red = IsRed(a.D1.Day- l.D2.Day))
    Group By Key = xx.PID Into G = Sum(xx.Red)
    Select Key, G
```

---

```
Function IsRed(ByVal dayx As Integer) As Integer
    If (dayx < -7) Then
          Return 1
       Else
          Return 0
       End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because LINQ to Entities can't figure out how to translate the IsRed function into SQL. You can create a custom SQL Function and tie that to your IsRed function, but honestly the easiest thing will be to just inline your code:

```
From xx In 
(From l In L3s
Join a In BLs On l.L3ID Equals a.L3ID
Order By l.ID
Select PID = l.ID,
Red = If(a.D1.Day - l.D2.Day < -7, 1, 0))
Group By Key = xx.PID Into G = Sum(xx.Red)
Select Key, G
```

Comment: StriplingWarrior; ternary operator usage is coorect.

Answer (score 2):

What that message is saying to you is that LINQ-to-Entities does not know how to translate a call to your custom function into SQL (well, technically, into *entity*-SQL, but that's not a relevant distinction here).

You won't be able to do this. The expression framework does not provide semantic conversion of any arbitrary function into SQL (which isn't possible, anyway, since SQL is not a turing-complete procedural language). If you want to do this, you'll have to embed that logic directly into your query.

Comment: Adam Robinson, Thanks for the suggestion.